# Objective-C: Circular progress view

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress

How to make progressView like in app store with using default progresView?

As image shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please look the link https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton hope this help

Comment: see this https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAProgressView

Comment: you'll need a custom control for this.   You can't do this with a UIProgressView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code, I have drew the circle for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

CAShapeLayer* outsideShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
outsideShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
outsideShapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
outsideShapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:outsideShapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];
outsideShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
outsideShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:outsideShapeLayer];


CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(102.5, 102.5, 95, 95);
shapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:shapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0;
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.75f;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks but how I can use this circle with UIProgressView?

Comment: You must have a timer or API to control your progress whether you use  UIProgressView or CustomProgressView(the circular one), if you want use both of them, just make sure they are controlled by the same controller.

Comment: If you have some question with animation, just change the shapeLayer's strokeEnd property.